# Noetherian quotient rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, noetherian

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $I,J$ ideals of $R$ such that $J$ is finitely generated and the rings $R/I$ and $R/J$ are Noetherian. Are the $R$-modules $R/J$, $J/IJ$, $R/IJ$ Noetherian? Is the ring $R/IJ$ is  Noetherian?

Comment: $R/J$ is a noetherian ring, which means that all its ideals are finitely generated. The $R$-submodules of $R/J$ are also $R/J$-submodules which are precisely the ideals of $R/J$. But those are all finitely generated which is equivalent to $R/J$ being noetherian.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Sebastian did the $R/J$ case in the comments.  Now $J/IJ$ is $J\otimes R/I$ which, since $J$ is finitely generated and $R/I$ is Noetherian (as an R-module), is a Noetherian R-module.
The exact sequence
$$ 0\rightarrow J/IJ \rightarrow R/IJ\rightarrow R/J\rightarrow 0$$
and the previous two results show $R/IJ$ is Noetherian.